# How to run cron job periodically within time range on linux?

Tags: linux, cron

I would like a cronjob that runs every 5min with the condition that it doesn't start at time 0.

Current schedule is:
*/5 * * * *

However, this will kick off the script at 00:00. I need something like (5-60)/5 * * * *

Thanks!

Comment: what is the difference between 60 and 0 in an hour?!

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I need the scrip to run every 5min expect during midnight.

Comment: It's OK. Please define the midnight range in the question.

Comment: 12:00 AM
In cronjob: 0 0 * * *

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a way to do this in cron.  You might be better off leaving the schedule as is, and checking the time in the beginning of your script, and using a condition to exit the script if it is not supposed to run at that time.

Comment: hmmm... that using a condition on exit sounds could work